# Can a collection have multiple iterators in Java?

Tags: java, collections, iterator

Is it possible to have multiple iterators in a single collection and have each keep track independently? This is assuming no deletes or inserts after the iterators were assigned.

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 15):

Yes.

Sometimes it's really annoying that answers have to be 30 characters.

Comment: Agreed.  Will Java spawn the threads automatically and synchronize

Comment: @cp: Iterators are unrelated to threads. Any threading has to be done by you.

Comment: So if I create two iterators of one collection they are not in separate threads and inserts/deletes will not be included in any use?

Comment: @cp: What happens is entirely up to you, depending on how you use the iterators and the underlying collection. If you start iterating through an iterator and then modify the collection without using the iterator, you'll get `ConcurrentModificationException` when you continue iterating.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it is possible. That's one reason they are iterators, and not simply methods of the collection.

For example `List` iterators (defined in `AbstractList`) hold an `int` to the current index (for the iterator). If you create multiple iterators and call `next()` a different number of times, each of them will have its `int cursor` with a different value.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. That depend of the implementation of the interface `Iterable<T>`.

Usually it should return new instance of a class that implement Iterable interface, the class AbstractList implements this like that:

```
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return new Itr(); //Where Itr is an internal private class that implement Itrable<T>
}
```

If you are using standard Java classes You may expect that this is done this way.

Otherwise You can do a simple test by calling `iterator()` form the object and then run over first and after that second one, if they are depend the second should not produce any result. But this is very unlikely possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Miterate {

    abstract class IteratorCaster<E> implements Iterable<E>, Iterator<E> {
        int mIteratorIndex = 0;

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return mStorage.size() > mIteratorIndex;
        }

        public void remove() {
        }

        public Iterator<E> iterator() {
            return this;
        }
    }

    class FloatCast extends IteratorCaster<Float> {
        public Float next() {
            Float tFloat = Float.parseFloat((String)mStorage.get(mIteratorIndex));
            mIteratorIndex ++;
            return tFloat;
        }
    }

    class StringCast extends IteratorCaster<String> {
        public String next() {
            String tString = (String)mStorage.get(mIteratorIndex);
            mIteratorIndex ++;
            return tString;
        }
    }

    class IntegerCast extends IteratorCaster<Integer> {
        public Integer next() {
            Integer tInteger = Integer.parseInt((String)mStorage.get(mIteratorIndex));
            mIteratorIndex ++;
            return tInteger;
        }
    }

    ArrayList<Object> mStorage;

    StringCast mSC;
    IntegerCast mIC;
    FloatCast mFC;

    Miterate() {
        mStorage = new ArrayList<Object>();

        mSC = new StringCast();
        mIC = new IntegerCast();
        mFC = new FloatCast();


        mStorage.add(new String("1"));
        mStorage.add(new String("2"));
        mStorage.add(new String("3"));
    }

    Iterable<String> getStringIterator() {
        return mSC;
    }

    Iterable<Integer> getIntegerIterator() {
        return mIC;
    }

    Iterable<Float> getFloatIterator() {
        return mFC;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Miterate tMiterate = new Miterate();

        for (String tString : tMiterate.getStringIterator()) {
            System.out.println(tString);
        }

        for (Integer tInteger : tMiterate.getIntegerIterator()) {
            System.out.println(tInteger);
        }

        for (Float tFloat : tMiterate.getFloatIterator()) {
            System.out.println(tFloat);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the concurrent collections you can have multiple iterators in different threads even if there inserts and deletes.