# Geotools nested loop over SimpleFeatureCollection

Tags: java, collections, iterator, nested-loops, geotools

I want to to do a nested loop over a SimpleFeatureCollection. For each point I need to find its neihgbours and process them.

However, SimpleFeatureCollection allows only iterators, but not array access, which makes it impossible (at least seems so) to implement a nested loop. This iterator doesn't have a previous() method, so I can't reset it and use two iterators over the same collection.

So I was wondering if there is any other way to access a feature by its index.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is a code example here:
    http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/main/collection.html#join

It shows how to nest loops:

```
void polygonInteraction() {
    SimpleFeatureCollection polygonCollection = null;
    SimpleFeatureCollection fcResult = null;
    final SimpleFeatureCollection found = FeatureCollections.newCollection();

    FilterFactory2 ff = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2();
    SimpleFeature feature = null;

    Filter polyCheck = null;
    Filter andFil = null;
    Filter boundsCheck = null;

    String qryStr = null;

    SimpleFeatureIterator it = polygonCollection.features();
    try {
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            feature = it.next();
            BoundingBox bounds = feature.getBounds();
            boundsCheck = ff.bbox(ff.property("the_geom"), bounds);

            Geometry geom = (Geometry) feature.getDefaultGeometry();
            polyCheck = ff.intersects(ff.property("the_geom"), ff.literal(geom));

            andFil = ff.and(boundsCheck, polyCheck);

            try {
                fcResult = featureSource.getFeatures(andFil);
                // go through results and copy out the found features
                fcResult.accepts(new FeatureVisitor() {
                    public void visit(Feature feature) {
                        found.add((SimpleFeature) feature);
                    }
                }, null);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                System.out.println("Unable to run filter for " + feature.getID() + ":" + e1);
                continue;
            }

        }
    } finally {
        it.close();
    }
}
```

If you want to ignore some features you have already visited, and skip content::

```
HashSet<FeatureId> skip = new HashSet<FeatureId>();
...
if( skip.contains( feature.getId() ) ) continue;
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is possible to have multiple iterators over a collection, provided that they are just reading, not modifying the collection. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315441/multiple-iterators-per-collection-java).

I'm hoping `SimpleFeatureCollection` is not an exception to the rule!

For a nested loop, you can just create another iterator for each run through the inner loop; you don't need to 'reset' the previous one.

Comment: Thanks, DNA. The thing is that I actually need to modify this collection (I need to mark already processed points by changing a certain property). I kinda figured it out, how to do what I want, it just looks so ugly. Basically, I'm creating a new collection and overwriting the iterator. Thanks, anyway

Comment: Just record the feature ids of features you have already hit in a HashSet<String>. Note GeoTools is structured this way to allow you to work with massive amounts of data, if you know you are working with small amounts of data copy the features into a List<Feature>.