# Allowing different ways of iterating through a class in Java

Tags: java, iterator, abstraction

## Context

I have the following class which represents a deck of cards, containing an array of Cards:

```
public class Deck {
    private List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>;
    
    ...
}
```

## Problem

I would like to be able to iterate through the Deck class in different ways. For example, in order, in random order, etc. In addition, I would like to do this while hiding the implementation of the class as much as possible.

## What I have tried

**1. Implementing Iterable<Card>** 
From my understanding, if I make the Deck class implement the Iterable class as follows:

```
public class Deck implements Iterable<Card> {
    private List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>;
    
    @Override
    public Iterator<Card> iterator() {
         ...
    }

    ...
}
```

it will only allow one way of traversing the deck.

**2. Returning a copy of the array in a different order** 
For example, for a random order:

```
public class Deck {
    private List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>;
    
    public List<Card> randomOrder() {
         List<Card> copy = new ArrayList<Card>( cards );
         Collections.shuffle(copy);
         return copy;
    }

    ...
}
```

This way seems to be the simplest but I feel reveals the implementation of the class a lot more.

## Conclusion

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Why do you think the second way "reveals the implementation"? In what way does it reveal the implementation? How does anyone know that you used a `List<Card>` to implement `Deck` just by seeing that `randomOrder` returns a `List<Card>`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a collection have multiple iterators in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315441/can-a-collection-have-multiple-iterators-in-java)

Comment: You can just provide multiple iterators for your class

Comment: IMO this requires first to define the purpose of the class precisely: Is a "Deck" in your case the set of cards that make up the deck or is it a *specific shuffle* of a deck? IMO you mostly likely need the second one and don't *usually* need the first one specifically (or can substitue a well-defined instance of the second for the first). If it's the later, then returning a new `Deck` from the `shuffle()` method would be appropriate (as would modifying the current instance, if you don't want/need immutable objects).